# Update Vendors in Sylius - Imagine Bundle Error (Symfony2)

Tags: symfony, e-commerce, composer-php, sylius

I am trying to install Sylius - Open Source E-Commerce based on Symfony2 from [this link](http://sylius.com/)
The composer can successfully pull the project files from github but while updating vendors i get this error

[UnexpectedValueException]
  'C:\wamp\www\sylius\vendor/liip/imagine-bundle/Liip/ImagineBundle/3e0aa0b8b
  218dab8fc7a752ff6d3a41e.4' is not a zip archive.

I have zip and git installed on my system.
Please help with your solutions and suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok..so i did this
I cleared the cache from the project folder and ran the command:
    php composer.phar update
And now all seems to be working fine without any error. All vendors successfully updated and downloaded the remaining ones.
Hope this helps someone